# Problema con tkinter notebook frame - Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en *Python*, la cual utiliza la *ttk* de *TKinter*.

Me gustaría cambiar el color de fondo de la aplicación (no el gris que sale por defecto) pero he probado de todo y no hay manera.

Lo más parecido es con *TFrame*:

```
self.style.configure("TFrame", background='green')
```

Pero solo me sale el color en la primera pestaña, cuando cambio a otra, ésta es de color gris.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Hola chujalt, deberías agregar un [mcve] para ver que widgets usas, cómo los posicionas, etc.Mencionas "pestañas", ¿Estás usando ttk.Notebook?

Comment: Si. Estoy utilizando ttk. Notebook. Lo acabo de solucionar, después de días peleando era una equivocación al iniciar la función. Lo pondré en el hilo. Gracias por contestar tan pronto  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Vaya, solucionado.

El problema venía en el inicio de la función de la segunda pestaña

```
class Volume(ttk.Frame):
 def __init__(self,name,*args,**kwargs):
   Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
```

La he cambiado a

```
class Volume(ttk.Frame):
 def __init__(self, main_window):
   super().__init__(main_window)
```

Y ahora funciona bien, el color de fondo está en las dos pestañas.

Gracias por todo y saludos.